# How to properly load SIDE_MODULE from MAIN_MODULE in Emscripten?

Tags: c, emscripten

I'm trying to create a simple example using `MAIN_MODULE/SIDE_MODULE` based on https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/wiki/Linking#general-dynamic-linking but cannot make it work.

Here's my code:

**main.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
int side(int a);
 
int main()
{
    printf("hello world %d\n", side(1));
}
```

**side.c:**

```
int side(int a)
{
    return a + 1;
}
```

**compile:**

```
emcc side.c -s SIDE_MODULE=1 -o side.wasm
emcc main.c -s MAIN_MODULE=1 -o main.html
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var Module
      = {
      preRun: []
      , postRun: []
      , print: function (e) {
        1 < arguments.length && (e = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).join(" "));
        console.log(e);
      }
      , printErr: function (e) {
        1 < arguments.length && (e = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).join(" "));
        console.error(e)
      }
    };
    Module.dynamicLibraries = ['side.wasm'];
  </script>
  <script async src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

If I run it with `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`, I get the following errors:

```
(index):19 Assertion failed: undefined
printErr @ (index):19
abort @ main.js:33157
assert @ main.js:1074
removeRunDependency @ main.js:1984
(anonymous) @ main.js:2274
Promise.then (async)
instantiateArrayBuffer @ main.js:2272
(anonymous) @ main.js:2301
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ main.js:2296
Promise.then (async)
instantiateAsync @ main.js:2288
createWasm @ main.js:2321
Module.asm @ main.js:2344
(anonymous) @ main.js:31495
(index):19 failed to asynchronously prepare wasm: abort(Assertion failed: undefined) at Error
    at jsStackTrace (http://localhost:8000/main.js:1626:13)
    at stackTrace (http://localhost:8000/main.js:1643:12)
    at abort (http://localhost:8000/main.js:33163:44)
    at assert (http://localhost:8000/main.js:1074:5)
    at removeRunDependency (http://localhost:8000/main.js:1984:5)
    at http://localhost:8000/main.js:2274:7
```

Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `-o main.html`??

Comment: Just tested your code with `emcc` v1.39.12. With `emcc main.c -s MAIN_MODULE=1 -o main.js`, not `main.html`, it works fine. Output: `hello world 2`.

Comment: @Azeem Thank you for testing it. Do you have any idea why it doesn't work on my macOS? I installed emscripten with the following: `./emsdk install latest-fastcomp && ./emsdk activate latest-fastcomp && source ./emsdk_env.sh`

Comment: @ZackLee: I tested it with `upstream`, not `fastcomp`. There's no mention of `fastcomp`. I'll test it again with `fastcomp`.

Comment: @ZackLee: Working fine with `fastcomp` as well with the correct output. However, two startup errors: `side.html:19 wasm streaming compile failed: TypeError: Failed to execute 'compile' on 'WebAssembly': Incorrect response MIME type. Expected 'application/wasm'.` and `side.html:19 falling back to ArrayBuffer instantiation`.

Comment: @ZackLee: What is your emscripten path when you run commands to compile? Please share the exact path and commands.

Comment: @Azeem I run the `emcc` commands in the path where `side.c` and `main.c` exist. It is `/Users/cuinjune/Desktop/module_test `

Comment: @ZackLee: So, you have set the `PATH` where `emcc` exists in `/<path>/emsdk/fastcomp/emscripten`? Please verify with `which emcc` and `whereis emcc`.

Comment: which emcc: `/Users/cuinjune/emsdk/fastcomp/emscripten/emcc` where emcc: `/Users/cuinjune/emsdk/fastcomp/emscripten/emcc`

Comment: @ZackLee: What is the version of `emsdk`? And, did you compile and run `main.js` instead of `main.html`? Please test again and update. Browser?

Comment: emcc -v: `emcc (Emscripten gcc/clang-like replacement + linker emulating GNU ld) 1.38.40
clang version 6.0.1 (/b/s/w/ir/cache/git/chromium.googlesource.com-external-github.com-emscripten--core-emscripten--fastcomp--clang 98df4be387dde3e3918fa5bbb5fc43e1a0e1daac) (/b/s/w/ir/cache/git/chromium.googlesource.com-external-github.com-emscripten--core-emscripten--fastcomp 1b4148f39a69c7fc62edadd85e4122b68694dfb7) (emscripten 1.38.31 : 1.38.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.5.0
Thread model: posix`

Comment: @Azeem Yes, I tried compiling and running `main.js` instead of `main.html` but it gives me the same error.

Comment: @Azeem My browser is the latest Chrome: Version 83.0.4103.116 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: @ZackLee: Right. Can you try with `var Module = {}; Module.dynamicLibraries = ['side.wasm'];`?

Comment: I just tried but still get the above error messages and `Uncaught (in promise) abort(abort(Assertion failed: undefined) at Error`

Comment: @ZackLee: Please make sure that your browser cache is cleared. You can work in Incognito mode. Can you test with a simple helloworld program to check to see if it's working at all? Also, observe the line numbers in the exceptions for any change.

Comment: @Azeem The helloworld program works fine if I don't use the `-s MAIN_MODULE=1` option. I've been using emscripten without any problem and I could also use `-s MODULARIZE=1` and successfully open a module. The `MAIN_MODULE/SIDE_MODULE` option is the only one that doesn't work for me so far. I also tried clearing the cache.

Comment: @ZackLee: That's strange. I'd suggest to test it one last time with `emcc main.c -s MAIN_MODULE=1 -s EXPORT_ALL=1 -s ASSERTIONS=1 -o main.js`. Otherwise, consider opening an issue.